# How to fix AAPT: error: '???dp' is incompatible with attribute layout_marginEnd (attr) dimension

Tags: android, android-studio

After install of android studio I wanted to create a test app so I added only one button to the default hello world app and run it but I got this error. (after search stackoverflow for similar problem and solution I ask a question......)

```
AAPT: error: '???dp' is incompatible with attribute layout_marginEnd (attr) dimension.
```

here is auto generated code by android studio:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="hello world!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="۳۲dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="۱۸۰dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used arabic numerals for `android:layout_marginTop="۳۲dp"` && `android:layout_marginEnd="۱۸۰dp"` use english numbering instead like `"10dp"`

Answer (score 2):

Change this:
android:layout_marginTop="۳۲dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="۱۸۰dp"
to:
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"

(inside the **Button** tag)

Comment: Thanks. that's true. Why? May you descript the reason....

Comment: Non-english numerals aren't allowed in XML. Please mark the answer with a green tick if it's a solution for you.

Answer (score 2):

Numbers written in a non-English language will probably be corrected by change

```
 android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="180dp"
```